# Enable checkbox from within Ajax success event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using the following line to disable all checkboxes on a page:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', 'true');
```

I then want to reenable them if the ajax call succeeds, but this doesn't seem to do it:

```
               $.ajax({
                   url: 'EditService.svc/whatever',
                   type: 'GET',
                   data: { "code": code },
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function () {
                       //clear status
                       $('.EditStatus').html('')
                       //reenable all checkboxes
                       $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', 'false');
                   },
                   error: function (a, b, c) {
                       $('.EditStatus').html("Database Error!");
                   }
               });
```

I don't understand why.  The //clear status portion works fine.

Comment: just realized it's                            $('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('disabled');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string 'true' evaluates to true, because it's a non-empty string, whereas 'false' is not falsy as it is not empty. Try:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', false);
```

and while this works:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', 'true');
```

You should still pass a boolean instead of a string.

If you are using jQuery 1.6+, you should use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) (and [`.removeProp`](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/)) instead.

Comment: ahhh that makes sense.  I ended up using                            $('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('disabled');
but since I can't answer my own question I'll accept yours :)

Comment: in 11 minutes... if I'm still awake.

Comment: or rather `.removeAttr("disabled");`

Comment: @naveen - the op has already worked that one out himself, I wanted to explain in JS terms why his `$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', 'false');` call was failing.

Comment: agreed :) +1: nice answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
if jQuery.version < 1.6:
    $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', false);
else:
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', false);
```

---

Side note: [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty) is better than `.html('')`. The intent is clearer and the code will run faster.

Comment: RE: Side Note
"29 occurrence(s) replaced."